# Is there any way to get CVE or USN ids that need to be installed?

Tags: 12.04, security

I'm looking to pull in what CVE or USN ids that apply to a security update before doing them. Is there any way?

Comment: Check the debian/changelog entry for the package that's being updated.  The CVEs / USNs are all listed there under "SECURITY UPDATE" in the changelog entries.

Comment: i'd like to do it via command not just pull the changelog for each package that needs to be updated

Comment: Short of looking at the changelog or the actual USNs that are sent out (there's a list you can subscribe to for those), it'll be a bit hard to *not* see all the updates included in a given package updates.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved in two steps:

- **Find security related packages that need to be updated:** I am running a modified version of the `update-notifier`'s `apt-check` script which takes an additional switch: `--security-package-names`, and outputs only the security related package names
- **Look up CVE's against those packages:** The `ubuntu-cve-tracker` project on launch pad can be used

Here are the step by step instructions:

**Getting a list of security related packages**

I have it as a gist (until I create a merge request in the relevant project in launchpad). For now it can be run as follows:

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ahmadnazir/c2444d6b09fd7bb4963a13bc577d92a3/raw/0231b94a4e46abe0a5959de5f84feda76ad2eb9d/apt-check.py \
  | python /dev/stdin --security-package-names \
  | column -t -s , \
  | sort
```

This gives an output of the format: **package name**, **installed version**, and **candidate version**:

```
...
thunderbird                          1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
thunderbird-gnome-support            1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
thunderbird-locale-en                1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
thunderbird-locale-en-us             1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
tzdata                               2016b-0ubuntu0.14.04                 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04
tzdata-java                          2016b-0ubuntu0.14.04                 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04
vlc-data                             2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1                 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2
vlc-nox                              2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1                 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2
wget                                 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.1                1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.2
...
```

**Looking up CVE's for the packages**

Check out ubuntu's cve tracker project on launchpad:

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-cve-tracker
```

Let's say you want to get the CVE for the `wget` package, you can run the following script

```
cd ubuntu-cve-tracker
./scripts/pkg_status wget
```

This gives an output similar to following:

```
                                           precise         trusty      vivid/spo       vivid/uc           wily         xenial        yakkety
CVE-2016-4971 wget:                       released      released*        needed*            DNE       released       released       released [out of sync] SUPPORTED medium
```

The first column in the result shows the CVE.

**Note:**

Make sure that `/etc/apt/sources.list` has the relevant sources for the scripts to work. I modified the some of the scripts to work only with trusty which is why I didn't have to do this.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: the CVE tracker is *huge*.  It will take a *lot of time* to clone that over.  You may have to wait a while before being able to search the updated lists of data.  (It takes 10 minutes to clone on my connection, the tracker is so huge)

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated command to get the CVE or USN IDs that need to be installed for a given bug.

You will have to either read the changelog for the packages in question, subscribe to the USN / CVE notifications, or check every package's page on Launchpad to see what the changelog for the given package in the given release has.

(There is no command you can just type to get the list, though.)